# Combinations to fill three boxes with 15 different weights.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, contest-math, combinations

We have 3 boxes that can carry maximum weight of 14kg and we have 15 objects with weights:

$$a_{1}=3 , a_{2}=4 , a_{3}=4 , a_{4}=2 , a_{5}=2 $$

$$a_{6}=3 , a_{7}=1 , a_{8}=4 , a_{9}=3 , a_{10}=3 $$

$$a_{11}=3 , a_{12}=2 , a_{13}=2 , a_{14}=2 , a_{15}=1 $$

With how many combinations can we place them (order doesn't matter) ?

All the numbers are kg.

What I've tried is to count. I was hoping there is a method to solve this without going arithmetically.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't enjoy Community's comments that so often say a question is unclear when it is not.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. This is not a "solve my problem for me" site. If you [edit] the question to show us what you have tried and where you are stuck we may be able to help.

Comment: Total weight is 39. I found 43 at my first count, so, with total 43, it was very simple. What is the context : scolar exercice ? I think the only way to solve this exercice is to compute each individual combination. No magic formula.

Comment: When you say "order doesn't matter," do you mean that the boxes are interchangeable?  And I echo the comment of @EthanBolker above that you need to edit the question to show us what you've tried.

Comment: I tried to count them all by hand at first. I was hoping there is a quicker method analytically. I don't know if there is any. 

Yes the boxes are interchangeable.

Comment: Is it required that all weights are placed in some box?

Comment: @PaulSinclair I moderately  disagree.  The total weights are $~39~$, which must be fit into $~3 \times 14,~$ which leaves $~3~$ units of *wiggle room*.  The only possible ways of distributing the *wiggle room* is (3-0-0), (2-1-0), (1-1-1). Each of these mutually exclusive wiggle room distributions must be manually explored.  For example, the (3-0-0) distribution requires that you pack the boxes (14-14-11).

Comment: @coffeemath  Please clarify the specific enjoyment that you have of the Community's comments.  As your comment is currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're enjoying.

Comment: @user2661923 - Your comment caused me to review the problem where I realized I had missed that there were three boxes. I had misinterpreted it as how many ways to choose items out of the 15 so that the total weight did not exceed 14 kg. @ Peter Schraum, my apologies for the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not an answer**. 
This is a long winded comment.

First of all, I agree with the comment of Ethan Bolker.  Despite the fact that the original poster (plausibly) is  untrained for this problem, you are still supposed to provide context, and show work.  See [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236) for details.

---

However, I can outline the analytical attack method that I would use.  The total weights are  39 , which must be fit into $~3 \times 14~$ which leaves  3  units of wiggle room.

The only possible ways of distributing the wiggle room is (3-0-0), (2-1-0), (1-1-1). Each of these mutually exclusive wiggle room distributions must be manually explored.

For example, the (3-0-0) distribution requires that you pack the boxes (14-14-11).

The next step is to re-index the weights, by size:

- $a_7, ~a_{15} ~\to~ b_1, ~b_2, ~$ respectively.
- $a_4, ~a_5, ~a_{12}, ~a_{13}, ~a_{14} ~\to~ c_1, ~c_2, ~c_3, ~c_4, ~c_5, ~$ respectively.
- $a_1, ~a_6, ~a_9, ~a_{10}, ~a_{11} ~\to~ d_1, ~d_2, ~d_3, ~d_4, ~d_5, ~$ respectively.
- $a_2, ~a_3, ~a_8, ~\to~ e_1, ~e_2, ~e_3, ~$ respectively.

---

For illustrative purposes, I will explain how I would then attack the 
(3-0-0) $~\longrightarrow~$ (14-14-11) case.

Since $~11~$ is the sole odd number in the group, I would focus on that.  The combined number of b's and number of d's must be an odd number, and the sum of these combined b's and d's must be some element in $~\{1,3,5,7,9,11\}.~$

This means that the sum of the combined c's and e's must be some element in $~\{10,8,6,4,2,0\}.$

For illustrative purposes, within the case of packing for box=11, consider the sub-case of the c's and e's totaling $~6,~$ and the b's and d's totaling $~5.$

The total of $~5~$ from the b's and d's requires 3-1-1, which can be done in $~\displaystyle \binom{2}{2} \times \binom{5}{1} = 5~$ different ways.

The total of $~6~$ from the c's and e's requires either 4-2 or 2-2-2.

There are $~\displaystyle \binom{3}{1} \times \binom{5}{1} = 15~$ different ways to achieve 4-2.

There are $~\displaystyle \binom{5}{3} = 10~$ different ways to achieve 2-2-2.

So, in the specific subcase of [odd = 5, even = 6], 
 there are $~5 \times 15 = 75 ~$ ways via [3-1-1:4-2], 
and there are $~5 \times 10 = 50 ~$ ways via [3-1-1:2-2-2].

Then, for each of the two possibilities, for this sub-case, 
[3-1-1:4-2] and [3-1-1:2-2-2], you then have to determine the total number of ways of splitting the remaining weights into {14:14}.

Obviously, this entire process is very tedious.  For the
(3-0-0) $~\longrightarrow~$ (14-14-11) case, you then have manually examine each of the other sub-cases of the combined b's and d's being some **other** element in $~\{1,3,5,7,9,11\}.$

Then, you have to rinse and repeat for the 
(2-1-0) and (1-1-1) wiggle room distributions.

---

The analysis can be facilitated by creating a database table of the various combination possibilities, and writing a computer program to do all of the calculations.

So,

- in the (3-0-0) $~\longrightarrow~$ (14-14-11) case
- within that, you have for the box=11 packing: the sub-cases of 
  $( ~\text{odd}, ~\text{even} ~) \in \{(11,0), (9,2), (7,4), (5,6), (3,8), (1,10)\}.$
- within that, exploring the $~(5,6)~$ sub-case specifically,
- you have the two mutually exclusive possibilities of 
  [3-1-1:4-2] $~\longrightarrow ~75$ 
  [3-1-1:2-2-2] $~\longrightarrow ~50.$
- then, for the [3-1-1:4-2] packing of one box, you have to similarly determine the number of distinct ways splitting the remaining boxes into 14 and 14.
- similar analysis then required for the [3-1-1:2-2-2] packing of one box.

To complete the illustration, suppose that you are exploring the [3-1-1:4-2] packing.

Then remaining is :

- 4 c's @2 each
- 4 d's @3 each
- 2 e's @4 each.

The way that I would attack this is that either the 4 d's
are together, or they aren't.  If they are together, the box can only be completed with a 2.

If they are not together, then each box has 2 3's, and either the 2 e's are together or they aren't.

**Warning**
Consider the specific packing of

$\underline{\text{Analysis-1}}$ 
box=11 :: [3-1-1:4-2] 
box=14 :: [3-3-4-4], $~~$ box=14 :: [3-3-2-2-2-2]

versus

$\underline{\text{Analysis-2}}$ 
box=11 :: [3-1-1:4-2] 
box=14 :: [3-3-4-2-2], $~~$ box=14 :: [3-3-4-2-2]

In Analysis-1 above, you are okay with the natural multiplication of possibilities.

**However**, in Analysis-2 above, you have to apply the over-counting adjustment factor of $~\dfrac{1}{2!}~$ because two of the three boxes have perfectly identical weights.  This is a hard concept to grasp.

I will illustrate it with a simpler example.

Suppose that you have $~4~$ distinguishable people, that you are going to assign to $~2~$ indistinguishable rooms, so that no room is empty.

The partition is either 3-1 or 2-2.

The distribution of 3-1 does have $~\displaystyle \binom{4}{1} = 4 ~$ possibilities, for which person will be by themself.

However, the distribution of 2-2 instead has $~\displaystyle \frac{\binom{4}{2}}{2!} = 3 ~$ possibilities.  One way of noting this is that there are exactly $~3~$ choices for who Person-1 will be partnered with.